# How to divide a table header into multiple lines in a table in an R markdown document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am making a table, which is wide only because table headers are long. I will like to use two (or more lines) to write a table header so that my table  in the final PDF document remains legible.

Comment: Could  you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are actually referring to `rmarkdown` and not `knitr` since you did not mention using `kable`. As such, you have more control over the format of the table.

`rmarkdown` is using pandoc directly, so it is informative to check [there](http://pandoc.org/README.html) for insight. Specifically, where the author discusses [tables in markdown](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables).

I tested just two of the formats, and they both supported multi-line headers: `multiline_tables` (conveniently named) and `grid_tables`, both of which are supported OOB by `knitr`. I rendered both into HTML and PDF (LaTeX), and got no errors on my side. I copied the examples from the website, and I added backslashes in the header to force multiple lines.

The `multiline_table` format:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Centered   Default           Right Left\
  Header    Aligned         Aligned Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
   First    row                12.0 Example of a row that
                                    spans multiple lines.
  Second    row                 5.0 Here's another one. Note
                                    the blank line between
                                    rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------
Table: Here's the caption. It, too, may span
multiple lines.
```

And the `grid_table` format:

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages\        |
|               |               | or\                |
|               |               |          whatever  |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
|               |               | - bright color     |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
|               |               | - tasty            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+

Table: Another table. This is the grid_table format.
```

And they render to:

[image]